# Парадокс времен

Tags: придаточное-предложение, времена

> Жди, пока не дали отмашку!

Как можно ждать то, что уже произошло?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как можно ждать то, что уже произошло?

Трудно ответить, это философский вопрос, далекий от филологии.

Но боюсь, вы неверно поняли смысл процитированной вами фразы. Ждать надо **не того, что произошло, а того, что еще только произойдет**.

Дело все в том, что грамматическое прошедшее время и даже его совершенный вид (дали) совсем не обязательно означает то, что действие в реальности произошло на момент события, о котором говорится. Подобное понимание не до конца справедливо даже в английском, где как известно, вообще на любую ситуацию свое грамматическое время, что уж говорить о русском, с его крайне бедной системой грамматических времен.

Если немного обобщать, то в русском языке чаще всего отношение времен в СПП (а так же в деепричастных конструкциях и некоторых других ситуациях) соответствует относительному времени в реальности. В данном случае это утверждение означает, что прошедшее время глагола "дали" и его совершенный вид характеризует состояние действия, когда можно будет прекратить выполнения импервтива "жди". Когда действие "дали" перейдет в состояние совершившего и УЖЕ произошедшего модно прекратить ждать. В тот момент оно и становится "прошедшим". Ничего более. Чисто грамматическое понимание "прошедшего времени".

(+) ====

Мне не нравится интерпретация, даннаz grizzly. Фраза понятная, грамматически  правильная, самодостаточная и ни в каких трактовках или контекстах не нуждается.

Означает она то, что и должна означать, синонимична (с точность до акцентов)
аналогичной с будущим временем:
***Жди, пока не дадут отмашку.***

В качестве доказательства того, что такой вариант с пошедшим временем вполне правилен и не нуждается в контексте - несколько цитат из классики.

> Отдохну немного и опять лавировать начну между подводными камнями,
> пока не потерплю полного крушения… [А. С. Новиков-Прибой. По-темному
> (1912)]

> Телятев. Так иди скорее, пока не забыл. Васильков. А ты куда же
> торопишься? [А. Н. Островский. Бешеные деньги (1869)]

> Поспеши, батюшка, гонца, пока не отдал богу душу. [И. И. Лажечников.
> Басурман (1838)]

> Я буду продолжать свое письмо во время и после поездки, а пока не
> собрался еще в путь, поговорим о другом. [А. Д. Салтыков. Письма из
> Индии (1841)] ←…→
>
> Скорее иди от меня прочь и беги, пока не постиг тебя меч мой!» [Ф. И.
> Буслаев. Повесть о горе и злочастии, как Горе-Злочастие довело молодца
> во иноческий чин (1856)] ←…→

(Все    примеры - из Нацкорпуса)
В последних примерах - так вообще полная аналогия.
Похоже, для придаточного при повелительном наклонении прошедшее время - вообще основной способ выражения действия при "пока не". Будущее сильно уступает по количеству примеров.

@user190920

> "жди, пока он не был здесь"

Фраза грамматически вполне корректна, хотя выглядит немного странноватой. Глагол "быть" в значении "находиться" как-то не завязывается на законченное событие, которого требует ситуация. Но в общем-то чего неправильного-то?

*Пока он не был здесь - жди, не болтай (с ним) о том, чего он не видел.*

Да, тут контекст тот еще нужен, но это из-за того, что глагол мало того, что плохо подогнан под ситуацию, так еще и несовершенного вида

Любой пример с другим глаголом можете привести? Такой, чтобы у вас тоже "не работало"?

*Не рассуждай о фильме, жди, пока не смотрел его.*
*Не рассуждай о фильме, жди, пока не посмотрел его.*

Разница только в том, что первая форма требует какого-то **смотрения** (не обязательно полного), а вторая - **просмотра**, видимо - законченного.

Вообще Несовершенный вид глагола действительно редкость в таких конструкциях, но тем не менее, ничего "неработающего" в нем нет.

@Sharon

> В этом примере, вероятно, говорится о близком будущем, когда событие
> ожидается с большой вероятностью.

***Живите, пока Земля не слетела с оси***
(Современный автор)

Это тоже о "близком будущем"? )))

(++) ====

> Я буду работать пока он ушел.

... и не пришёл назад.

> Я работаю пока он сидел

... сидит и будет сидеть

> ```
> Я работал пока он сидит,
> ```

... но теперь и работать перестал (хотя он все еще на нарах).

> ```
> Я буду работать пока он сидит.
> ```

Здесь и комментировать нечего

> ```
> Я буду работать пока он сидел.
> ```

Аналогично "работаю". "Пока сидел, сидит и будет сидеть".

> Я буду работать, в то время как он сидел.

А вот это уже смысловой тупик. "В то время как" предполагает **одновременность** действия, а глаголы в таком употреблении четко относятся к абсолютному, не к относительному времени.  То есть не могут быть одновременными ни в каком смысле. Хотя, если хорошо подумать, чего не бывает... ))))

**А! придумал!** Можно же подменить значение "в то время как" с временн**о**го на более сейчас распространенное причинно-противительное. )))

***Я буду работать, в то время как он сидел и (поэтому) не может устроиться на работу..***

При таком прочтении одновременность не требуется.

Comment: Если вы считаете это грамматической нормой, тогда вы должны объяснить почему эта норма не работает в примерах типа "жди, пока он не был здесь"

Comment: @user190920 Я ничего никому не должен. )))) И уж совсем не понимаю вашу посылку-силлогизм *"если... то..."*. А что да самой конструкции  "пока не был здесь" то она грамматически вполне "работает". Только смысл у неё странноватый. Я ответ дополню.

Comment: Да, похоже вы правы, надо подумать. Пока поставлю правильный ответ. Спасибо! А с союзом пока такой номер вроде не проходит ни при каких обстоятельствах. "Жди пока он сидел тут" это уж точно не корректно.

Answer (score 4):

> Как можно ждать то, что уже произошло?

Парадокса нет. Ждут при такой фразеологии совсем не "**отмашки**". Если "*Жди, пока не дали отмашку!*" произнесено адекватно ситуации, то "**ждать**" побуждают с известным адресату **действием**  - мол ничего не предпринимай, **пока** сохраняется ситуация "отмашки **не было**" и её может не последовать *вообще* (в этом случае можно "ждать" *отбоя*). В этом и есть смысловое отличие от варианта *Жди, пока не **дадут** отмашку!* (= дождись отмашки, после этого действуй как условлено).

Comment: В такой интерпретации "Жди, пока не дали отмашку" = "Жди, пока не дают отмашку (сохраняется ситуация что отмашки не было)". Отмечу, что в первом предложении у нас союз ПОКА НЕ, а во втором ПОКА с глаголом "не дают".

Comment: *Ждут при такой фразеологии совсем не "отмашки"* Ничего не понял. А чего ждут-то если не отмашки?! Можно, конечно, утверждать, что ждут не отмашки, а момента, когда она будет дана, но не более. Но вы-то не об этом, а о чем-то глобальном...

Comment: Я считаю ответ Alex_ander ЛУЧШИМ и наиболее ИНФОРМАТИВНЫМ. Я понимаю его мысль так. Ждут действительно не отмашки, а другой информации, например, о каких либо действиях по особому указанию. И только если таких указаний так и не поступило, то в определенный момент будет сообщено, что ждать больше не нужно. И вопрос к Alex_ander. Как вы думаете, этот вариант можно каким-то образом связать с условным наклонением (там тоже используется форма прошедшего времени). А условность в том, что действие (отмашка) может состояться, но может и не состояться в будущем, если не будет дополн. информации.

Comment: Ценность же ответа в том, что в нем указана семантическая разница между двумя формами (пока не дадут и пока не дали). Конечно, в соответсвующей литературе об этом, как я полагаю, написано, но интересно и самим подумать, как классифицировать этот вариант по семантическому принципу. К примеру, что-то вроде отложенной вероятности.

Comment: @behemotus Чего именно ждут? Ситуация неопределенная: "жди" здесь - синоним императивов "погоди", "повремени" (с известным из контекста действием).

Comment: @Sharon Грамматических признаков сослагательного наклонения здесь не видно. Смысловая особенность состоит в _неопределенности_ того, последует ли упомянутая "отмашка". Вместо неё косвенно _допускается_ ситуация отмены указаний к действию: ничего не делай, **по крайней мере**, до обозначенного момента.

Answer (score 2):

Имелось в виду что-то вроде: "Жди. [потому что] Отмашку пока [ещё] не дали". Из контекста это, наверное, очевидно, но всё равно при такой пунктуации выглядит в лучшем случае стилистической небрежностью. Приведите, пожалуйста, контекст или ссылку на него, а то ведь не понятно, что обсуждаем.

**Дополнение**.

**user190920**,
Вот Вам два предложения:
(1) Идите, пока не взошла луна.
(2) Идите, пока не взойдёт луна.
Попытайтесь набрать в гугле в кавычках предложение (1). Ссылок выпадет совсем немного, посмотрите их.

У лингвистов уже 50 лет существует традиция сравнивать (1) и (2). При этом все отмечают, что (1) не эквивалентно (2), но эквивалентно следующему: "Идите! Луна (ещё) не взошла!". (Сравните, кстати, с моей интерпретацией в начале ответа :)

Несмотря на всё это, я не согласен с тем, что обсуждаемое в вопросе предложение корректно. Пусть это будет моим личным мнением (я оставлю его пока без доказательства), но советую поискать работы лингвистов по теме "особенности употребления глаголов ожидания с союзом *пока*".

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, вы серьезно не понимаете смысл исходной фразы? Или полагаете её грамматически некорректной? Мне кажутся надуманными ваши попытки придать фразе какой-то странноватый смысл, да ещё списать все на контекст.

Comment: Спасибо посмотрю. Но, пример с луной мне видится неудачным. Во-первых, сразу же, напрашивается совершенно не к месту интерпретация "Идите, а то взойдет луна", которая только отвлекает. Во-вторых, ваша с лингвистами интерпретация "Идите, луна пока не взошла" = "Идите, пока Луна не взошла" явно не состоятельна. В первом предложении у нас наречие "пока" с глаголом "не взошла", а во-втором союз "пока не" с глаголом "взошла". Это совершенно разные оперы.

Comment: user190920 Вон, вам здесь уже целый учебник по альтернативному синтаксису предложили (и Вы его с удовольствием подтвердили). Ничего, "мы с лингвистами" этот плюрализм как-то переживём :)

Answer (score 2):

*Жди, пока **не дали** отмашку. –  Жди, пока **не дадут** отмашку.*

В некоторых специальных контекстах с референцией **к будущему может употребляться прошедшее время.**

[http://rusgram.ru/Будущее_время#152](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%91%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F#152)

Варианты возможны различные, эта тема подробно излагается в литературе, например: Бондарко А.В. Вид и время русского глагола. – М., 1971

В этом примере, вероятно, говорится о близком будущем, когда событие ожидается с большой вероятностью.

Пример:
*― Ищите, ищите! ― кричал я. ― Ищите, иначе мы **погибли***! [В. Губарев. Трое на острове (1950-1960)]

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

**Мне нравятся у grizzly  предложения про луну**, там действительно четко определяется **РАЗНЫЙ СМЫСЛ** – именно это важно и именно тогда можно использовать форму прошедшего времени, а не **когда кому захочется**. Поэтому  в Русской корпусной грамматике, на которую я даю ссылку, написано: **В НЕКОТОРЫХ СПЕЦИАЛЬНЫХ КОНТЕКСТАХ**.

В данном примере я понимаю **разный смысл** так.

(1) ***Идите, пока не взошла луна***.  Идите, пока еще темно, потом будет идти сложнее.

(2) ***Идите, пока не взойдёт луна.*** Идите пока темно, а потом остановитесь.

Во втором предложении четко указано время, а в первом случае **полного соответствия нет**, и это **один из признаков замены** будущего времени прошедшим.

Но это не единственный признак, вероятно, в **специальной литературе** проводится их **анализ**  (на книгу я тоже указала в ответе), за что меня и «отблагодарили» минусовкой ответа и соответствующими комментариями.

Поэтому **не стоит думать**, что замена всегда возможна. Не изучая этого вопроса, мы можем определить такую возможность только **на слух.**

Comment: Sharon, не могу с вами согласиться. У нас нет нет семантики будущего времени, ни близкого, ни какого еще. У нас есть конструкция "пока не", она принчипиально отличается от "иначе".  А пример, который вы привели, сопровождается к тому же совершенно не приненимым к нашуме примеру вводной: ***От неконтролируемых глаголов со значением негативной ситуации также возможны употребления с референцией к близкому будущему — с оттенком прогноза, соответственно:***

Comment: Тема статьи, на которую я даю ссылку, – ПРОШЕДШЕЕ ВРЕМЯ В ЗНАЧЕНИИ БУДУЩЕГО.  Это неправильно? Все остальное, включая пример – цитаты. Я привела ссылку на источник только потому, что без ссылки на что-либо академическое  считаю ответы разговорами и мнениями, так как это вполне серьезный вопрос  о грамматике. Укажите другой источник, если этот не подходит.

Comment: Ссылки приводятся именно для того, чтобы можно было проверить цитирующего не только на предмет  добросовестности цитирования, но и на правильность им понимания цитируемого применимости к разбираемой цитирующим проблеме.  Вот по второй причине я с вами и не согласен.

Comment: *Укажите другой источник, если этот не подходит* - это некорректное требование. Я не обязан искать источники для оправдлания ваших  заблуждений. С позиций научного этикета вы и только вы обязаны обосновать пригодность ваших положений.