# Сочетание времен

Tags: времена

Скажите, возможно ли такое построение предложения: "И они отправились отдыхать, ужинать и обсудить то, что им еще предстояло сделать".

Comment: Похожий вопрос https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462968/Парадокс-времен/462971#462971

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это вполне корректное построение предложения. Оно хорошо подходит к случаю, когда все действия находятся в прошлом - например, автору известно, что персонажи действовали по результатам упомянутого обсуждения, и как именно действовали (= что им "предстояло"). Но автор мог и иначе подойти к развитию сюжета - не ретроспективно описывать события, а приблизить предмет "обсуждения" к текущему (для персонажей) моменту: ни он сам, ни персонажи ещё не знают, что именно "предстоит" (как далее поступят персонажи), - это выяснится при обсуждении. В этом случае вместо прошедшего времени (предстояло) уместно было бы настоящее (предстоит). Ср.: "я спросил его, что он хочет".

Comment: А если я немного перестрою предложение? 
"И они отправились отдыхать, ужинать и обсудить то, что еще не успели сделать".

Comment: Тогда нужно "отдохнуть, поужинать и обсудить".

Comment: Тогда совсем не по замыслу... Нужен длительный и неторопливый процесс. Поужинать совсем не подходит что-то... Интересно, а почему "обсудить" мы не можем отнести к "отправились"? Они отправились отдыхать и они отправились обсудить?

Comment: Скажите, какие правила можно посмотреть на эту тему? Ощущение, что я отправилась в совсем дальнее плавание с этим предложением:)

Comment: "Обсудить" плохо сочетается с глаголами несовершенного вида - в этом конкретном контексте (общего запрещающего правила нет, проблема стилистическая). Если вы оставляете их неизменными, то логичнеее "обсуждать". Тогда ясно, что намерение "отправившихся" состоит в посвящении некоторого времени всем перечисленным действиям.

Comment: Поискам закономерностей для случаев, когда сочетание совершенного и несовершенного вида уместно, посвящают статьи, подобные этой: https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/o-sochetaemosti-glagolov-sovershennogo-vida-s-perfektnym-i-aoristicheskim-znacheniem-s-drugimi-vidovremennymi-glagolnymi-formami

Comment: Спасибо, попробую почитать. Тогда первый вариант из всех предложенных наиболее благозвучный?